# How can I see a list of all the publicly accessible links/pages on my website?

Tags: dns, hyperlink, public

I would like to see a list of all the publicly accesible links on my website so I know which pages a user has access to. Is there a website or application that will crawl my website and display such information?

Answer (score 1):

If your site is already online you could easily get that information using [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/). You could also just look for `site:http://www.yoursite.com` on Google to get a list of the pages that were crawled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running a recursive [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) (by passing the -r option):

```
wget -r http://www.example.com
```